# Is this phrase an insult or jealousy?

Tags: translation, meaning

> 図体ばっかりでかくなりやがって

The person who says it is short but he's also very rude. The people he's talking to just worked out, so I don't know if he meant `only their bodies grew but their brain didn't`, or if it means something like `ugh you got so big` (I didn't).

Comment: any other context available? It seems like an insult, but specifically what was happening just before he said it?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.nihongomaster.com/dictionary/entry/1172/yagaru) could help.

Answer (score 5):

As I said in a comment I think looking at the [usage and meaning of やがる](https://www.nihongomaster.com/dictionary/entry/1172/yagaru) could help. It is a suffix of the verb which indicates hatred and contempt, or disdain for another's action. In case you already knew this, forgive me for pointing it out. Could still help others understand though.

Anyway, this gives a clear indication of the speaker's feelings towards what's happening. Therefore, I would say it's more of an insult than jealousy. Obviously though, an insult could be generated by jealousy as well, but that depends on the context. The bottom line is, what this guy means is: *you are just getting bigger physically!* (Or more literally: *nothing else but your body is getting bigger*). And the nuance of disdain/insult is given as I mentioned by the use of やがる as suffix to でかくなる.

**PS.** Let me add one thing in case it's not clear. The "insult" here is not underlined by やがる. This suffix only indicates disdain for something, not necessarily an insult. See this example from the link I provided:

> 昔はペチャパイだったのに、いつの間にかこんなに大きくなりやがって。 She used to be flat-chested - just
>   when did she get so large?

The insult nuance is highlighted by the combination of that with (図体)ばっかり, which, as you mentioned, means *nothing else* but your body is getting big (probably implying the brain is still small). This combined with the disdain given by やがる suggests it is an insult. I mean, if there was no ばっかり, it might simply be that the speaker does not like that the other guy got so big (as in the example above), not necessarily insulting him for this.

Answer (score 0):

Without any other context, I don't think you can make any inferences about it being an insult about the other person's brain, or an envious complaint about the speaker not matching up. More context might make this clearer, but...

taking a quick look at weblio for 図体{ずうたい},

https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%9B%B3%E4%BD%93

It seems to mean "body mass" or "body size" ... And the weblio entry actually lists as an example sentence, a very similar insult to the one in your question:

> 「図体ばかり大きくて、なんの役にも立たない」

This seems like a common way to insult someone who has purposely built up their body but isn't doing anything useful with it, or getting enough results out of it.

So **図体ばっかりでかくなりやがって**  likely is trying to imply something similar, like:

"All you've done is increased your body mass (for no reason/meaninglessly)."  or

"Just increasing your body size (and not improving anything else, is stupid)."

or if you want to get really loose with the translation, a more colloquial expression with a similar meaning is something like:

"Bigger isn't always better, you know."